# One of my fields is a JSON object in the form of this in Contenful. The data types are dynamic. How do I query this schema using graphql?

Tags: graphql, contentful

It is a JSON object with an array called "blocks". This is the structure of my JSON field in Contentful called "content". The structure can be dynamic as you can see "value" has string values and also array of strings

```
{
"blocks": [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "value": "Getting Started"
    },
    {
        "type": "title",
        "value": "Getting Started",
        "link": {
            "Getting": "youtube.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "quote",
        "value": "Getting Started",
        "link": {
            "Getting": "youtube.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "list",
        "value": [
            "list 1",
            "list 2",
            "list 3"
        ],
        "link": {
            "list 1": "google.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "image",
        "value": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473580044384-7ba9967e16a0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
    },
    {
        "type": "video",
        "value": "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"
    },
    {
        "type": "divider"
    }
]
```

}

I am using Gatsby and graphql to fetch it

```
return graphql(
`
  {
    allContentfulBlog {
      edges {
        node {
          content {
            blocks {
              type
              value
              link
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Please provide more details about the implementation and what you think is relevant and don't add pictures, add code which is far more easy to copy paste and test

Comment: I just added the code blocks